# Foreach if multidimensional otherwise no looping, cleanest solution

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have some markup that needs to be looped accordingly depending on the array, if it is multidimensional i have to loop it one way, if not i do not have to loop it.

As it is now i solve this by doing a big 'ol if/else and print the "static" markup if its not multidimensional, and loop the markup if it is. This is ugly as heeell and makes me use 2 identical blocks of markup.

```
if (count($data_array) == count($data_array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
    { block of html }
else
{ looped-almost same block of html }
```

Anyone got a better solution for this, i'd be happy to implement it instead :)

Edit: To clearify , i have a table that has properties looped, or not looped.

```
foreach($i as $b => $v)
$v['item']
```

where `$v['item']` runs through the table if the array is multidimensional 
if the array is not multidimensional i print the table with simply `$i['item']`

wich makes me use 2 identical html-blocks the only difference is the $v / $i

Comment: both blocks of html are exactly same or different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you updated your answer, I think that simply checking for `$array['item']` with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) could solve your problem.

Example:

```
if(isset($array['item'])) {
    // Do non-recursive stuff
}
else {
    // Do more checks and recursive stuff
}
```

---

**Old answer:**

Have you thought about [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array)?

```
for($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        // Do multidimensional stuff
    }
    else {
        // Do normal stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure that looks better i guess, but it still wont solve the redundancy issue with $value['item'] and $yourArray['item'] , the markup still needs to be duplicated.

Comment: You did not mention `$value['item']`. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: is_array() will not resolve the issue correctly becaue i think he want to check whether the array is single or multi dimensional.

Comment: is_array would work, because $v would not be an array if the array is not multidimensional, but the isset wont resolve my redundancy issue, i dont think atleast

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing like so:

```
  if(is_array($v))
    {
        $table_array = $v;
    }
    else
    {
        $table_array = $i;
        $single = true;
    }
```

inside the foreach loop, and at the end of the loop

```
if(isset($single))
    break;
```

not that hot.... but atleast i dont duplicate the html :)